# Unable to obtain Facebook Fan page access token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-page

I am trying to post content on a Facebook fan page from a CMS. I have lost my time just trying to get access token for that page. I am using latest **php facebook SDK** (Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.2))

I am logged in with permissions: `manage_pages`, and if I do `$Facebook->getUser()`, I am getting my facebook `userID`.

Then I execute this:

```
$fanPage = $Facebook->api('/' . $PAGE_ID .  '?fields=access_token&access_token='. $Facebook->getAccessToken());
```

I receive an array with `pageID` only, and without an `access_token`.

If I try this code:

```
$fbUser = $Facebook->api('/me/permissions?access_token=' . $Facebook->getAccessToken());
```

it invalidates my Facebook session and I have to login via Facebook again.

This was working few months ago, and just stopped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get all your pages and their `access_token` values, you have to call this API

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' =>'app_id', 'secret' =>'app_secret',));
$facebook -> setAccessToken($access_token);
$res = $facebook -> api("/me/accounts", "GET");
```

Then you have an **Array** of all your pages and it's `access_tokens`

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' =>'app_id', 'secret' =>'app_secret',));
$facebook -> setAccessToken($access_token);
$res= $facebook -> api("/YOUR_PAGE_ID?fields=access_token", "GET");

$page_access_token = $res["access_token"];
```